# Any API to prevent Windows 8 from going into connected standby mode?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

I need to disable [connected standby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn481224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mode until my Desktop application has finished. The desired behavior should be similar to what happens when I connect to that machine via Remote Desktop. That is, the screen is switched off, but the system doesn't go into sleep until I disconnect.

Is there any documented or undocumented way to get the same behavior for my application?

I tried [`PowerSetRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` and/or `PowerRequestAwayModeRequired`, but the system still goes into connected standby mode in a few mins. I currently use `PowerRequestDisplayRequired` to keep it alive, but the screen always stays on.

**EDITED.** This is the test application. The timer is ticking for no more than 5 minutes after I press the hardware power button and the screen turns off (running on battery).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CsTestApp
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Load += MainForm_Load;
        }

        void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // init timer

            var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += delegate 
            { 
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("CsTestApp: " + DateTime.Now); 
            };
            timer.Start();

            // set GUID_EXECUTION_REQUIRED_REQUEST_TIMEOUT

            IntPtr pActiveSchemeGuid;
            var hr = PowerGetActiveScheme(IntPtr.Zero, out pActiveSchemeGuid);
            if (hr != 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)hr);
            Guid activeSchemeGuid = (Guid)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pActiveSchemeGuid, typeof(Guid));
            LocalFree(pActiveSchemeGuid);

            int savedTimeout;
            hr = PowerReadDCValueIndex(
                IntPtr.Zero,
                activeSchemeGuid,
                GUID_IDLE_RESILIENCY_SUBGROUP,
                GUID_EXECUTION_REQUIRED_REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                out savedTimeout);
            if (hr != 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)hr);

            hr = PowerWriteDCValueIndex(
                IntPtr.Zero,
                activeSchemeGuid,
                GUID_IDLE_RESILIENCY_SUBGROUP,
                GUID_EXECUTION_REQUIRED_REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                -1);
            if (hr != 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)hr);

            // create power request

            var powerRequestContext = new POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT();
            powerRequestContext.Version = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION;
            powerRequestContext.Flags = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING;
            powerRequestContext.SimpleReasonString = "Disable Connected Standby";
            var powerRequest = PowerCreateRequest(ref powerRequestContext);
            if (powerRequest == IntPtr.Zero)
                ThrowLastWin32Error();

            // set PowerRequestExecutionRequired

            if (!PowerSetRequest(powerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestExecutionRequired))
                ThrowLastWin32Error();

            this.FormClosed += delegate
            {
                timer.Dispose();

                PowerClearRequest(powerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestExecutionRequired);
                CloseHandle(powerRequest);

                hr = PowerWriteDCValueIndex(
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    activeSchemeGuid,
                    GUID_IDLE_RESILIENCY_SUBGROUP,
                    GUID_EXECUTION_REQUIRED_REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                    savedTimeout);
                if (hr != 0)
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)hr);

            };
        }


        // power API interop

        static void ThrowLastWin32Error()
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        enum PowerRequestType
        {
            PowerRequestDisplayRequired = 0,
            PowerRequestSystemRequired = 1,
            PowerRequestAwayModeRequired = 2,
            PowerRequestExecutionRequired = 3,
            PowerRequestMaximum
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct PowerRequestContextDetailedInformation
        {
            public IntPtr LocalizedReasonModule;
            public UInt32 LocalizedReasonId;
            public UInt32 ReasonStringCount;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string[] ReasonStrings;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_DETAILED
        {
            public UInt32 Version;
            public UInt32 Flags;
            public PowerRequestContextDetailedInformation DetailedInformation;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT
        {
            public UInt32 Version;
            public UInt32 Flags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string SimpleReasonString;
        }

        const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION = 0;
        const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING = 0x1;
        const int POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_DETAILED_STRING = 0x2;

        static readonly Guid GUID_IDLE_RESILIENCY_SUBGROUP = new Guid(0x2e601130, 0x5351, 0x4d9d, 0x8e, 0x4, 0x25, 0x29, 0x66, 0xba, 0xd0, 0x54);
        static readonly Guid GUID_EXECUTION_REQUIRED_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = new Guid(0x3166bc41, 0x7e98, 0x4e03, 0xb3, 0x4e, 0xec, 0xf, 0x5f, 0x2b, 0x21, 0x8e);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr PowerCreateRequest(ref POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT Context);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool PowerSetRequest(IntPtr PowerRequestHandle, PowerRequestType RequestType);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool PowerClearRequest(IntPtr PowerRequestHandle, PowerRequestType RequestType);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);

        [DllImport("PowrProf.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern UInt32 PowerWriteDCValueIndex(IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid SchemeGuid,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            int AcValueIndex);

        [DllImport("PowrProf.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern UInt32 PowerReadDCValueIndex(IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid SchemeGuid,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            out int AcValueIndex);

        [DllImport("PowrProf.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern UInt32 PowerGetActiveScheme(IntPtr UserPowerKey, out IntPtr ActivePolicyGuid);
    }
}
```

This is the output from `powercfg.exe /requests`:

```
EXECUTION:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\avo\Test\CsTestApp.exe
Disable Connected Standby
```

Comment: Have you tried [SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @EricBrown, yes I tried it first before `PowerSetRequest`, it didn't help.

Comment: Hm.  `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` *should* be the only item required; which device are you having problems with?

Comment: @EricBrown, it's an 8" ASUS VivoTab Note 8, this one uses Intel Z3740 CPU. I think it would be the same for any Bay Trail SoC device, as the drivers are pretty much the same and supplied by Intel.

Comment: @EricBrown, besides setting `PowerRequestExecutionRequired`, do I need to keep some actual activity going, like sending some data to a socket?

Comment: Looking through the sources I have available, most places just use `PowerRequestExecutionRequired`, and then perform normal activity (typically using network/file system).  A couple of places use both `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` and `PowerRequestDisplayRequired`; it's not clear from local context if it's actually showing something (playing media, for example).

Comment: @EricBrown, it appears `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` [is limited to 5 mins only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23424457/1768303).

Comment: @avo - Can you run `powercfg /sleepstudy` while your app is running, and send me the results?  You can contact me via my blog.  My contacts here in MSFT say that `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` should suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently there's a (poorly) documented timeout value associated with `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` so that "misusing" the API would not delay an actual sleep request for AoAc machines.

In your case, probably your best bet is to use [`PowerWriteACValueIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the timeout (-1 disables the timeout):

```
    ReturnCode = PowerWriteACValueIndex(NULL,
                                   pGuidActivePowerScheme,
                                   &GUID_IDLE_RESILIENCY_SUBGROUP,
                                   &GUID_EXECUTION_REQUIRED_REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                                   -1);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I tried it but it did not help. I updated the question with the code, I use `PowerWriteDCValueIndex` there as I need to run the device on battery. I appreciate your help a lot, it's great to have an MSFT person looking into this.

Comment: @avo - you're almost there - you need to set the active scheme using [`PowerSetActiveScheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372758(v=vs.85).aspx) to commit any changes to the power scheme.  (And don't forget to restore the timeout after you're done...)

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is this still the best way to handle this in Windows 10? 2) Will this prevent Windows 10 from rebooting due to an update? I have an app that is used for monitoring industrial processes that can last 24 hours or more. We've had cases where Windows 10 updated and rebooted in the off-hours and invalidated the data. I'm suspicious that we need to use Win 10 Pro and turn off updating since this is messing up mission critical data collection.

Answer (score 4):

Here is [a similar question, unanswered](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6c135adb-7993-4691-b700-bd463ed8816c/windows-8-connected-standby-vs-desktop-audio-player-application?forum=windowssdk). I tried `PowerSetRequest` / `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` on my Z3700-based tablet, and I'm seeing the same behavior, the tablet goes into connected standby mode in ~5 mins regardless of this power request.

There's not so much information available on the web about connected mode internals, but I've found the following downloadable document: ["Introduction to Connected Standby"](https://web.archive.org/web/20131006031854/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj248729.aspx). Here is the relevant part about entering connected standby mode:

> **Phase name**:
> Connection Phase.
>
> **Description**:
> The system is checking for remote desktop connections.
>
> **Tasks performed**:
> • Determine if remote desktop session(s) exist.
> • Begin tracking outstanding Power Requests.
>
> **Exit when**:
> There are no remote desktop sessions connected.
>
> ...
>
> **Phase name**:
> Desktop Activity Moderator (DAM) Phase.
>
> **Description**:
> The system pauses desktop applications to reduce.
>
> **Tasks performed**:
> • Check for outstanding Power Requests (`PowerRequestExecutionRequired`).
> • Wait for outstanding Power
> Requests to be dropped by the application, or enforce a maximum
> time-out on battery power (5 minutes).
>
> **Exited when**:
> All outstanding Power Requests have been cleared by applications
> or the maximum time-out has been reached. their consumption during Connected Standby.

So, there's indeed some special treatment for remote connections, but for other services you have as many as 5 minutes to finish or pause your `PowerRequestExecutionRequired` activity. In my experience, this is happening even when the tablet is powered.

**IMO, that's a bad design decision**. It is **not** a Windows RT tablet, it's full-featured Windows 8.1 Pro machine and there has to be a way to keep it alive on batteries if we want so, at least for trusted desktop apps.

It's possible to [disable connected standby mode altogether](https://superuser.com/questions/710913/how-to-disable-connected-standby-in-windows-8), but in such case the hardware power button cannot be used to turn the monitor off and on.

So, I hate to be a this-is-not-possible guy, but I think there is no official method to disable connected standby the way the remote access daemon does it. I hope someone will post a better answer.

**Updated**, this document also mentioned the "Maintenance Phase":

> The system executes Maintenance Tasks.
>
> • Wait for maintenance tasks to complete if running
>
> (most common on AC power).
>
> Exited when… No system maintenance tasks are running.
>
> • Typically, less than 1 second.
>
> • The system is most likely to block on maintenance phase on AC power.

Perhaps, it's possible to start an ongoing maintenance task via Windows Task Scheduler API, although it's not clear if CS mode won't be entered anyway if *running on battery power*. I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

this may very be the lamest workaround, but if you keep the groove music app playing in the background it should still keep your pc awake for other processes